# Sharepoint 2010 ALERT settings - customize possible set of lists

Tags: alert, development, caml-query

I want to customize possible set of lists on which user can set "alerts ON". 
Customizing just ribbon button ("Alert me") for not showing on specific list isn't enough because - on some list on which is alert button visible he can pick "manage my alerts" and choose whatever lists he want and which are created in that web site.

Summarum: I want, if user want to set alert on few lists, to he be able to set on just e.g. 3 of them, not all possible list or document libraries.

Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom permission level, that does not have the "Create Alerts" right. Assign the permission to the user access of the lists that you don't want them creating alerts on. You will most likely have to break the permission inheritance.